# C# Timer inside a property

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, checkbox, timer

I'm trying to implement a timer for a checkbox. The binding for the checkbox is done using the CaptureColorBind property. When ever I click the capture color  checkbox (captureColor = true), it needs to be checked for 5 seconds and then checkbox needs to be unchecked. I'm trying to print the datetime before and after the timer to verify. Its printing the before time properly, but the datetime I print in the elapsed event handler gets printed n times depending on the number of times I click the capture color checkbox. That is the first time I click, it prints the date and time once, the second time I click, it prints twice and so on. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
private System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
public bool CaptureColorBind
    {
        get
        {
            return this.captureColor;
        }

        set
        {
            this.captureColor = value;
            if (captureColor == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine();
                timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(capturecolor_timer);
                timer.Interval = 5000;
                timer.Enabled = true;
            }
            if (null != this.PropertyChanged)
            {
                this.PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("CaptureColorBind"));
            }
        }
    }

    // Timer for capturecolor checkbox      
    private void capturecolor_timer(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
            timer.Enabled = false;
            this.captureColor = false;
            //this.colorCheckbox.IsChecked = false;
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine();
            if (null != this.PropertyChanged)
            {
                this.PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("CaptureColorBind"));
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding a new event handler every time the value is set. You should only add it once.

Try adding the event handler in the object's constructor so it only gets set once, and just re-enabling the timer when the property is set.

```
private System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
public MyObject()
{
    timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(capturecolor_timer);
    timer.Interval = 5000;
}
```